# How to Display Array Values using Nested For loops?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, nested

Before we begin, i am new at programming and C# language, So please bear with me.
The problem i am having is to display two individual array values in front of each other like this :

Integer Type : sbyte, byte, short, ushort
Real Floating point types : float, double

The Code I have tried is :

```
string[] VariableTypes = { "Integer Type", "Real Floating Point Types" };

string[] IntergerTypes = { "sbyte", "byte", "short", "ushort" };

for (int i = 0; i <= VariableTypes.Length - 1; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<=IntergerTypes.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(IntergerTypes[j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(VariableTypes[i] + " : ");
}
```

Output i am getting :

sbyte byte short ushort Integer Type :
sbyte byte short ushort Real Floating Point Types :

Comment: where would "float, double" be coming from?

Comment: are you sure you not missing anything in input data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] VariableTypes = {
  "Integer Type", "Real Floating Point Types" 
};
string[][] NumberTypes = {
  new string[] { "sbyte", "byte", "short", "ushort" },
  new string[] { "float", "double" }
};

for (int i = 0; i < VariableTypes.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(VariableTypes[i] + " : ");
    for(int j = 0; j < NumberTypes[i].Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(NumberTypes[i][j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another array to hold the values you want to relate to `Real Floating Point Types` and then conditionally check the variable type to see which integer types are associated with it.

```
string[] VariableTypes = { "Integer Type", "Real Floating Point Types" };
string[] FloatingPointTypes = { "float", "double" };
string[] IntergerTypes = { "sbyte", "byte", "short", "ushort" };

for (int i = 0; i <= VariableTypes.Length - 1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(VariableTypes[i] + " : ");

    if(VariableTypes[i] == "Integer Type")
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=IntergerTypes.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(IntergerTypes[j] + ", ");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=FloatingPointTypes.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(FloatingPointTypes[j] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion, it would be cleaner do this without the nested loops if all you're wanting is a way to achieve the mentioned output:

```
string[] FloatingPointTypes = { "float", "double" };
string[] IntergerTypes = { "sbyte", "byte", "short", "ushort" };

Console.WriteLine("Integer Type: " + string.Join(", ", IntergerTypes));
Console.WriteLine("Real Floating Point Types: " + string.Join(", ", FloatingPointTypes));
```

Additionally, you could utilize a class to make this a bit more streamline for you. See the following:

```
public class VariableType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> DataTypes { get; set; }
}
```

and use this class to achieve your desired outcome via the following:

```
var variableTypes = new List<VariableType>
{
    new VariableType
    {
        Name = "Integer Types",
        DataTypes = new List<string>{ "sbyte", "byte", "short", "ushort" }
    },
    new VariableType
    {
        Name = "Real Floating Point Types",
        DataTypes = new List<string>{ "float", "double" }
    }
};

foreach(var variableType in variableTypes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(variableType.Name + " : " + string.Join(", ", variableType.DataTypes));
}
```